# Method to find the differential equation given the solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know how to proceed with this problem:

> Find the homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients and minimum order that has as a (one of them) solution: $t\cdot sin(t)$.

I don't know how to start. How we can inverse the process to find the DE that has this solution without even know the order of it?

Thanks.

Comment: do you know how to solve DEs with constant coefficients?

Comment: @supinf Yeah, finding the characteristic polynomial associated to its matrix, then finding the roots and the roots in the form $e^{root\cdot t}$ form a basis of the solutions of the homogeneous DE.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a solution if you start differentiating:
$$
 y(t)= t \sin(t)
 \\
 y'(t)= \sin(t) + t\cos(t)
 \\
 y''(t) =  \cos(t) + \cos(t)- t\sin(t)
 \\
\dots
$$

until you can find a linear combination of these functions that results in $0$. (due to your minimal requrement, you have to argue that there are no possible linear combinations before that).

Comment: I'm not sure this approach works. If
$$
a(2\cos t-t\sin t)+b(\sin t+t\cos t)+ct\sin t=0
$$
then $t=0$ immediately implies $a=0$, and similarly $t=-1$ implies $b=0$ and $t=1$ implies $c=0$.